# Unable to include js in magento product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, layout-update

I am trying to add a custom js file into my catalog product view page but the same is not happening.

I placed my js file inside skin\frontend\default\ucs_personalization\js\personalization.js

And below is the snippet of layout catalog.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
.
.
.
<reference name="head">
<action method="addJs"><script>ucs_personalization/js/personalization.js</script></action>
</reference>
.
.
.
</catalog_product_view>
```

On the page view source i can see it takes the js from root\js. Below is page source script. It says that magento looks the js file inside root js directory

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://192.168.100.68/magento/js/ucs_personalization/js/personalization.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make it use the skin folder like this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/yourfile.js</name></action>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use this structure:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>ucs_personalization/js/personalization.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

you should have your `personalization.js` in following tree format:

`js/ucs_personalization/js/personalization.js`

**If you want to keep your `js` inside `skin` folder then use this:

```
<action method="addItem">
  <type>skin_js</type>
  <name>js/personalization.js</name>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/personalization.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```